# Create Unique ID by combining First Name, Middle Name and Date of Birth

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, lines-of-code

I have the following dataframe of names and date of birth. The data type is all over the place, missing values and so on, like this one:

```
Employee type   First Name  Middle Name Last Name   Date of Birth
Employee    Paulo       Cortez  01-01-90
Employee    Paulo   Ricardo Cortez  01-01-90
Employee    Paulo       Cortez  01-01-90
Employee    Paulo       Cortez  02-01-90
Employee            Cortez  
Employee    Paulo       Cortez  $
Employee    Maria   ##  Silva   02-01-90
Employee    o,89    Pedro       s
Employee    Maria       Silva   
Employee    Maria       Silva   02-01-90
Employee    Joao        Augusto 02-01-90
Employee    Maria       Silva
```

I need a way to create an ID column, taking whatever value I have in the combination of names + date of birth and create an unique ID per each of the rows like this one:

```
Employee type   First Name  Middle Name Last Name   Date of Birth   ID
Employee    Paulo       Cortez  01-01-90    10000
Employee    Paulo   Ricardo Cortez  01-01-90    10001
Employee    Paulo       Cortez  01-01-90    10000
Employee    Paulo       Cortez  02-01-90    10002
Employee            Cortez      10003
Employee    Paulo       Cortez  $   10004
Employee    Maria   ##  Silva   02-01-90    10005
Employee    o,89    Pedro       s   10006
Employee    Maria       Silva       10007
Employee    Maria       Silva   02-01-90    10008
Employee    Joao        Augusto 02-01-90    10009
Employee    Maria       Silva       10007
```

The ID should start in 10000
What would be the best way to create this column?

Comment: I'm confused. Are there duplicate entries for some employees? If so, how would you identify them as dups? Identifying the actual dups seems like the real challenge. If you could remove all dups, then create an increasing ID or do a hash of the values you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df
###
  Employee type First Name Last Name Date of Birth
0      Employee      Paulo    Cortez      01-01-90
1      Employee      Paulo    Cortez      01-01-90
2      Employee      Paulo    Cortez      01-01-90
3      Employee      Paulo       NaN      01-01-90
4      Employee      Maria     Silva      02-01-90
5      Employee        NaN     Silva      04-10-90
6      Employee       Joao   Augusto      12-11-89
```

Here you can see the difference between `cumsum()` and `ngroup()`.

- Use `dropna=False`, otherwise groups within `na` value would fall into the same group(`ID`).
- Utilize `sort=False` within `ngroup()` method, otherwise

> The numbers given to the groups match the order in which the groups would be seen when iterating over the groupby object, not the order they are first observed.

```
df['ID'] = (df.groupby(['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Date of Birth'] ,dropna=False).cumcount() == 0).cumsum() + 9999
df['ID_ngroup'] = df.groupby(['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Date of Birth'] ,sort=False ,dropna=False).ngroup() + 10000
print(df)
###
  Employee type First Name Last Name Date of Birth     ID  ID_ngroup
0      Employee      Paulo    Cortez      01-01-90  10000      10000
1      Employee      Paulo    Cortez      01-01-90  10000      10000
2      Employee      Paulo    Cortez      01-01-90  10000      10000
3      Employee      Paulo       NaN      01-01-90  10001      10001
4      Employee      Maria     Silva      02-01-90  10002      10002
5      Employee        NaN     Silva      04-10-90  10003      10003
6      Employee       Joao   Augusto      12-11-89  10004      10004
```

Comment: Hello
The cumsum code is generating me the error:TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'Timestamp' but the ngroup is working, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can assign each group a unique id with [pd.groupby.ngroup](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html). One small issue with this method (Thanks to @milkwithfish for reminding) : It will assign -1 to each group if there is a null value in any of the groups. So, filling null values will be a safer method:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['id'] = df.groupby(['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Date of Birth']).ngroup() + 10000
```

Comment: Sorry, the ID should start in 10000

Comment: That was the easy part but I edited the answer nevertheless

Comment: doesn't it cause problems if there are missed values?

Comment: @milkwithfish Actually, it will assign `-1` to each group that has a null value, so filling null values will be safer. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that you don't have duplicates and create an ID column:

```
df['ID'] = range(len(df))
```